Motivic $L$-functions came from automorphic representations
Langlands in his 1978 ICM talk made a conjecture that all motivic $L$-functions should arise as automorphic $L$-functions. A part of this conjecture, namely for some Hasse-Weil $\zeta$ functions is a consequence of automorphy lifting theorems.
How about those motivic $L$-functions which are not Hasse-Weil $\zeta$ functions? Is there any known result for them?
